# Having trouble of rotated square when getting its corners

Tags: html, math, canvas, trigonometry

Can anybody know what's the problem of my formula when getting corners of my rotated square. It seems right when I rotate my square from 1 to 10 degrees, but when you gave it 10 plus rotation I get wrong corners position.

This code is from my getCorners() method of my Square class:

```
var hx = 0,
    hy = 0;

hx = hy = this.size / 2;

var cos = Math.cos(this.rotation * Math.PI / 180),
    sin = Math.sin(this.rotation * Math.PI / 180);                      

var corners = {
      a: { x: this.x - hx, y: this.y - hy },
      b: { x: this.x + hx, y: this.y - hy },
      c: { x: this.x + hx, y: this.y + hy },
      d: { x: this.x - hx, y: this.y + hy }
};

var tl = corners.a,
    tr = corners.b,
    br = corners.c,
    bl = corners.d;

corners.a.x = (tl.x - this.x) * cos - (tl.y - this.y) * sin + this.x;
corners.a.y = (tl.x - this.x) * sin + (tl.y - this.y) * cos + this.y;                                           

corners.b.x = (tr.x - this.x) * cos - (tr.y - this.y) * sin + this.x;
corners.b.y = (tr.x - this.x) * sin + (tr.y - this.y) * cos + this.y;                                                                   

corners.c.x = (br.x - this.x) * cos - (br.y - this.y) * sin + this.x;
corners.c.y = (br.x - this.x) * sin + (br.y - this.y) * cos + this.y;                                                                                           

corners.d.x = (bl.x - this.x) * cos - (bl.y - this.y) * sin + this.x;
corners.d.y = (bl.x - this.x) * sin + (bl.y - this.y) * cos + this.y;
```

For full source code and running program here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/css3guy/8B2eT/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula (rotation matrix) is correct but you are using reference values which means you are updating the values in the first part of the calculations and then the rest of the calculations uses that new value instead of the one you intend.

One way to fix this is to define your objects this way instead (just shown for one corner):

```
// clone the values instead of referencing them
var tl = {x:corners.a.x, y:corners.a.y},
    ...

// now you have a copy to work with here instead of accumulated updates
corners.a.x = (tl.x - this.x) * cos - (tl.y - this.y) * sin + this.x;
corners.a.y = (tl.x - this.x) * sin + (tl.y - this.y) * cos + this.y;
```

**[Modified fiddle (only one corner fixed)](http://jsfiddle.net/8B2eT/1/)**

I would strongly encourage though to refactor and use a common rotation/translation function instead.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean common rotation/translation function instead? sorry i'm new about this. anyway thanks you solved my problem.

Comment: @css3 glad it worked out. I mean just a single function that do the math independent on corner. Just pass it a corner/rotation/translation and it spits out a new one. This way you can maintain code in one place, reduce code, increase speed, make it more readable etc. Just a tip.